# Convert image with use of imerode, imdilate, im2bw, imshow

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to convert below image A to image B. how can i achieve that. plz help.

[image]

Comment: can you show it in an example...

Comment: Don't have Matlab on this pc, so it will have to wait a bit or someone else could give the example. But there are examples on the doc page I linked to, see if you can make those work! :)

Comment: will wait.. nd meanwhile will try

Comment: @Junuxx: i tried. and it worked thanks. :) got the soloution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try morphological operations as i c for this case the unwanted objects are identical and have smaller size than the others.
just identify ur structuring element by using strel fn , just c matlab help then u have a lot of options to use fns: imerode , imdilate, bwmorph 
change the strel shape size and using  imerode till u got only the large objects then use imdilate with the same shape &  size

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of techniques to do this task. you can simply run a Sobel mask on the image and find the gradients, then segment the image with a scalar threshold like value 100, and run circle Hough transform for detecting circles. This algorithm returns you the center of the circles and the radius. By this information you can keep the pixels within that circle and remove others.

As another technique, you can search for the rectangles, for this action, after the Sobel mask, you can run line Hough transform to find the lines fit on the edges, then find the intersections of the line visible in the sobel image, by which you can decide where the rectangles are located, then its time for removal.

enjoy ;)

Comment: Didnt you read the title? It's an exercise that's supposed to be solved with morphological operations, not edge detection and stuff.